# solr / tomcat7 doesn't come back up after a crash

Tags: unix, solr, tomcat7

I keep getting issues with *Solr* crashing on my server. Its hardly a busy  site, so I'm baffled as to why it keeps doing it.

Anyway, as an intermediary - I'm written a shell script that runs on a cron as root:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=(tomcat7 nginx mysql);

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "Checking $i"
    if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $i | wc -l) > 0 ))
    then
    echo "$i is running!!!"
    else
    echo "service $i start\n"
    service $i start
    fi
done

# re-run, but this time do a restart if its still not going!
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "Checking $i"
    if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $i | wc -l) > 0 ))
    then
    echo "$i is running!!!"
    else
    service $i restart
    fi
done
```

..then this cron (as root)

```
 */5 * * * * bash /root/script-checks.sh
```

The cron itself seems to run just fine:

```
Checking tomcat7
service tomcat7 start\n
Checking nginx
nginx is running!!!
Checking mysql
mysql is running!!!
Checking tomcat7
Checking nginx
nginx is running!!!
Checking mysql
mysql is running!!!
```

...and Tomcats status seems ok:

```
root@domain:~# service tomcat7 status
â tomcat7.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat7)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2016-03-21 06:33:28 GMT; 4 days ago
  Process: 2695 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

...yet my script, can't connect to Solr:

```
Could not parse JSON response: malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "Can't connect to loc...") at /srv/www/domain.net/www/cgi-bin/admin/WebService/Solr/Response.pm line 42. Can't connect to localhost:8080 Connection refused at /usr/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 49.
```

If I manually run a "restart":

```
service tomcat7 restart
```

...it then starts working again. Its almost like the 2nd part in my shell script isn't working.

Any suggestions?

My Solr versions are as follows:

```
Solr Specification Version: 3.6.2.2014.10.31.18.33.47
Solr Implementation Version: 3.6.2 debian - pbuilder - 2014-10-31 18:33:47
Lucene Specification Version: 3.6.2
```

**UPDATE:** I've read that sometimes updating the **maxThreads** can help with crashes, so I've changed it to 10,000:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="10000" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I guess time will tell, to see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: What do the logs say about Solr when it crashes?

Comment: Which version of Solr?

Comment: I'm having a bit of an issue getting into the admin panel. I enter: mysite.net:8080/solr , but it just hangs (and eventually gives a "*The connection has timed out*" error) . Bit confusing, as accessing it in SSH via "lynx", it works ok (just not very pretty or easy to use!). I can't actually figure out the version number, as its just a load of text not formatted nice :(

Comment: @MatsLindh - I've just updated my post with the new version. The Solr port was blocked, which is why I couldn't get into the admin panel :)

Comment: @TMBT - I'm not sure where to look for the log file, to find that out :)

Comment: @TMBT - any ideas on the log file location? I'm using a **tomcat7** version, and have: `/var/log/tomcat7` ... but I can't find a **solr.log** file in there. **catalina.out** has some contents in there, but nothing about it being down

Comment: Try /your/path/to/solr/server/logs.

Comment: @TMBT - thanks. I found this folder, but it looks empty: `locate logs | grep "solr"   `, reported: 
`/usr/share/solr/logs`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I never got to the bottom of why it wouldn't restart... but I have worked out why it was crashing. Before, we had it on 2048mb RAM Linode server, but when we moved over to Apache2, I setup a 1024Mb server, and was going to upgrade it to 2048mb one we had it all working. However, we put it live - but I forgot to update it to the 2048mb server, so Nginx/Apache2/Tomcat/MySQL etc, were all trying to run on a pretty slow server.

We found that Solr was dying with an OOM (out of memory) error, which is what gave us the clue.

Hopefully this helps someone else, who may come across this.